# php function..any replacement for msqli_fetch_assocs() for this function to output a boolean?

Tags: php, mysql

Please i need help on this my codes.how can i make this function output a boolean results thus true(1) and false (0).My codes are as below:

```
function user_active($username){
    global $username;
    global $con;
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = mysqli_query($con,
        "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as count
        FROM `users` 
        WHERE `username` = '$username' 
        AND `active` = 1") 
        OR  die(mysqli_error());

    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    //echo $result['count'];
    return ($result['count']  >= 1) ? true : false;
}
```

This is the codes for the conditions that  i want to check for with the above function

```
if(user_active($user_data['username']) === false){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

but it keeps on returning false...

Comment: What is it returning now?  What does `$result['count']` equal?

Comment: it ouputs its results in a form of an array..

Comment: Your code should work as you want. It shouldn't return an array.

Comment: There's no need to use the ternary, since `>=` returns true or false. So just `return $result['count'] >= 1;`.

Comment: Don't use `global $username` since `$username` is passed as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions above but the problem is still persisting...

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem with this conditional codes

```
if(user_active($user_data['username'])!= 1){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

instead of

```
if(user_active($user_data['username']) === true){
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

in my initial codes..thanks for ur suggestions